# Visa on Arrival in Jakarta

Tags: visas, indonesia, jakarta

Apparently Indonesia has recently suspended their Visa exemption for short stays. It looks like the only way to get in at the moment is an e-Visa (which requires a local sponsor) or Visa On Arrival, which seems to be difficult and cumbersome.

1. Does anyone has recent experience with Visa on Arrival in Jakarta or
   any other entry point in Indonesia?
2. Does anyone know whether the Visa exemption has actually been suspended or not? Most website seem to say that it's still in place. I tried the Indonesian Embassy chatbot which gave me link to the the qualifying countries (https://www.imigrasi.go.id/id/foreign_passport/) The link is big old 404.

It it matters I was planning to travel with an US or German passport, whatever is easier.

See:
[https://kemlu.go.id/bern/en/news/17810/entering-indonesia-updated-on-27-april-2022#:~:text=Due%20to%20the%20Covid%2D19,are%20suspended%20until%20further%20notice](https://kemlu.go.id/bern/en/news/17810/entering-indonesia-updated-on-27-april-2022#:%7E:text=Due%20to%20the%20Covid%2D19,are%20suspended%20until%20further%20notice).

Comment: Why do you think that's the visa on arrival is cumbersome? I am going there in a few days, and it seems that all is required is to update my vaccination record online, then things will be easy once i am there. I heard from people who went there recently that's the thing that takes time is if you do not update the vaccination record before going there..

Comment: I think if you follow that steps and you are vaccinated, you won't have any issues.

Comment: The only websites that I found recommended against it because there way long lines and it was  very time consuming. However, I have no idea how old this information is.

Comment: @NeanDerThal: where do you upload the vax info? I downloaded the app but so far haven't figure out how to upload stuff.

Comment: @Hilmar the [link](https://vaksinln.dto.kemkes.go.id/sign/in) is available in the same page you linked as well